# Polynomial can be written as a sum of two monic polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Hints only**

> Prove that any monic polynomial (a polynomial with leading coefficient 1) of degree $n$ with real coefficients is the average of two monic polynomials of degree $n$ with $n$ real roots.

**Hints only.**

I have been thinking about this, By the intermediate value theorem, it must suffice that, if a polynomial $P(x)$ has $n$ distinct roots exactly then it must have $n+1$ sign changes overall.

By $P(x)$ and $g(x)$ I am referring to the two monic polynomials. By $f(x)$ I am referring to the main polynomial.

$P(x)$ and $g(x)$ must have the form: $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)....(x-r_n)$.

But it still seems difficult to prove. Is induction a way?

**Hints only please.**

Comment: Try doing it by induction on $n$: $Q(x) = xq(x) + a$ where $Q$is of degree $n$, $q$ of degree $n-1$ and $a$ a constant. Also note your problem says $n$ real roots, it doesn't say they are distinct, so be cautious.